# Tinkerpop and ArangoDB : MissingPropertyException: No such property: graph for class: Script1

Tags: docker, gremlin, arangodb, gremlin-server

I am trying to use ArangoDB as a [community supported provider](https://github.com/ArangoDB-Community/arangodb-tinkerpop-provider) for [Tinkerpop](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/) so that I can use Gremlin in a Python project but I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] DefaultGremlinScriptEngineManager - Could not create GremlinScriptEngine for gremlin-groovy
java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: graph for class: Script1
```

I have followed the Wiki to define the [`properties`](https://github.com/ArangoDB-Community/arangodb-tinkerpop-provider/wiki/Configuration) and [`yaml`](https://github.com/ArangoDB-Community/arangodb-tinkerpop-provider/wiki/Server) configuration files.

Here is my `properties` configuration `conf/modern-arangodb.properties`:

```
gremlin.graph = com.arangodb.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.ArangoDBGraph
gremlin.arangodb.conf.graph.db = tinkerpop
gremlin.arangodb.conf.graph.name = modern
gremlin.arangodb.conf.graph.vertex = Place
gremlin.arangodb.conf.graph.edge = Transition
gremlin.arangodb.conf.arangodb.hosts = 127.0.0.1:8529
gremlin.arangodb.conf.arangodb.user = root
gremlin.arangodb.conf.arangodb.password = openSesame
```

Here is my `yaml` configuration `conf/gremlin-server-arangodb.yaml`:

```
host: localhost
port: 8182
scriptEvaluationTimeout: 30000
channelizer: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.channel.WebSocketChannelizer
graphs: {
  modern: conf/modern-arangodb.properties}
scriptEngines: {
  gremlin-groovy: {
    plugins: { org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.jsr223.GremlinServerGremlinPlugin: {},
               com.arangodb.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.ArangoDBGremlinPlugin: {},
               org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.ImportGremlinPlugin: {classImports: [java.lang.Math], methodImports: [java.lang.Math#*]},
               org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.ScriptFileGremlinPlugin: {files: [scripts/empty-sample.groovy]}}}}
serializers:
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerIoRegistryV3d0] }}             # application/vnd.gremlin-v3.0+gryo
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}                                                                       # application/vnd.gremlin-v3.0+gryo-stringd
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerIoRegistryV3d0] }}         # application/json
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV2d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerIoRegistryV2d0] }}         # application/vnd.gremlin-v2.0+json
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1 }                                                                                                            # application/vnd.graphbinary-v1.0
processors:
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.session.SessionOpProcessor, config: { sessionTimeout: 28800000 }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.traversal.TraversalOpProcessor, config: { cacheExpirationTime: 600000, cacheMaxSize: 1000 }}
metrics: {
  consoleReporter: {enabled: true, interval: 180000},
  csvReporter: {enabled: true, interval: 180000, fileName: /tmp/gremlin-server-metrics.csv},
  jmxReporter: {enabled: true},
  slf4jReporter: {enabled: true, interval: 180000}}
strictTransactionManagement: false
idleConnectionTimeout: 0
keepAliveInterval: 0
maxInitialLineLength: 4096
maxHeaderSize: 8192
maxChunkSize: 8192
maxContentLength: 65536
maxAccumulationBufferComponents: 1024
resultIterationBatchSize: 64
writeBufferLowWaterMark: 32768
writeBufferHighWaterMark: 65536
ssl: {
  enabled: false}
```

I then use the [ArangoDB docker image](https://www.arangodb.com/download-major/docker/) (Version 3.6.3) and run:

```
docker run -p 8529:8529 -e ARANGO_ROOT_PASSWORD=openSesame arangodb/arangodb:3.6.3
```

Then I run the Gremlin Server (Version 3.4.6) and run:

```
GREMLIN_YAML=conf/gremlin-server-arangodb.yaml bin/gremlin-server.sh console
```

After which the terminal returns the aforementioned error `No such property: graph for class: Script1`

Comment: i tried this with apache tinkerpop gremlin server `3.3.10` and it has the same issue

Comment: typically, that means there was a graph initialization problem and that problem should be visible in the console/log output. is there a stacktrace present somewhere? consider keeping a TinkerGraph configured also to test basic connectivity. you might also try to use Gremlin Server 3.3.3 until you get this basic connectivity working since the most recent version of that arangodb provider is bound to that TinkerPop version: https://github.com/ArangoDB-Community/arangodb-tinkerpop-provider/blob/2.0.2/pom.xml#L27

Comment: yes @stephenmallette I figured out the problem and you are correct, i updated the graph name and it resolved the issue. Put and answer below.

Comment: i should have noticed that in the configuration you posted - sorry. at least you figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

The issue was related to the configuration.

the configuration file `conf/gremlin-server-arangodb.yaml` mentions a key/value pair list of graph defined by properties files:

```
graphs: {
  modern: conf/modern-arangodb.properties}
```

Then in the scriptEngines.gremlin-groovy.plugins it references:

```
ScriptFileGremlinPlugin: {files: [scripts/empty-sample.groovy]}
```

Which specifies a graph with the name `g`.

(In Script file `scripts/empty-sample.groovy`):

```
globals << [g : graph.traversal().withStrategies(ReferenceElementStrategy.instance())]
```

The global `graph` is not defined, which in fact is called `modern` in the `yaml` file.

## Resolution

Therefore a minor change in the `gremlin-server-arangodb.yaml` file was made. In addition, the `conf/modern-arangodb.properties` graph name was changed to match.

Updated `conf/modern-arangodb.properties`:

```
gremlin.graph = com.arangodb.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.ArangoDBGraph
gremlin.arangodb.conf.graph.db = tinkerpop
gremlin.arangodb.conf.graph.name = graph
gremlin.arangodb.conf.graph.vertex = Place
gremlin.arangodb.conf.graph.edge = Transition
gremlin.arangodb.conf.arangodb.hosts = 127.0.0.1:8529
gremlin.arangodb.conf.arangodb.user = root
gremlin.arangodb.conf.arangodb.password = openSesame
```

Updated `conf/gremlin-server-arangodb.yaml`:

```
host: localhost
port: 8182
scriptEvaluationTimeout: 600000
channelizer: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.channel.WebSocketChannelizer
graphs: {
  graph: conf/modern-arangodb.properties}
scriptEngines: {
  gremlin-groovy: {
    plugins: { org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.jsr223.GremlinServerGremlinPlugin: {},
               com.arangodb.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.ArangoDBGremlinPlugin: {},
               org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.ImportGremlinPlugin: {classImports: [java.lang.Math], methodImports: [java.lang.Math#*]},
               org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.ScriptFileGremlinPlugin: {files: [scripts/empty-sample.groovy]}}}}
serializers:
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerIoRegistryV3d0] }}             # application/vnd.gremlin-v3.0+gryo
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}                                                                       # application/vnd.gremlin-v3.0+gryo-stringd
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerIoRegistryV3d0] }}         # application/json
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV2d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerIoRegistryV2d0] }}         # application/vnd.gremlin-v2.0+json
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1 }                                                                                                            # application/vnd.graphbinary-v1.0
processors:
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.session.SessionOpProcessor, config: { sessionTimeout: 28800000 }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.traversal.TraversalOpProcessor, config: { cacheExpirationTime: 600000, cacheMaxSize: 1000 }}
metrics: {
  consoleReporter: {enabled: true, interval: 180000},
  csvReporter: {enabled: true, interval: 180000, fileName: /tmp/gremlin-server-metrics.csv},
  jmxReporter: {enabled: true},
  slf4jReporter: {enabled: true, interval: 180000}}
strictTransactionManagement: false
idleConnectionTimeout: 0
keepAliveInterval: 0
maxInitialLineLength: 4096
maxHeaderSize: 8192
maxChunkSize: 8192
maxContentLength: 65536
maxAccumulationBufferComponents: 1024
resultIterationBatchSize: 64
writeBufferLowWaterMark: 32768
writeBufferHighWaterMark: 65536
ssl: {
  enabled: false}
```